# no module name flask for some reason

Tags: python, flask, backend

I am building my first backend website, but now when I try to start the db from the shell I get this:

> no module named flask

The file structure:

These are all in a folder called

```
5_judges.py  __pycache__  backend.py  dives.py           static     textcase.py
__init__.py  backend.py   dive.js      documentation.txt  templates
```

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///posts.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: Just do a `pip install flask` in your command terminal for your computer or your virtual environment.

Comment: i did it i have a new problem that when i run db.create_all() it gives me an error can't set attribute

Comment: What's the attribute error you're getting? Make sure you have all dependencies installed. Just try running flask on it's own without any other imports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the principle of *separation of concerns* when building your flask project. Following this principle all your files/modules/packages are well organized and are re-usable.

Use this structure when creating your flask app:

```
project_folder
    |---------- app.py
    |---------- config.py
    |---------- .env
    |---------- requirements.txt
    |---------- .flaskenv
    |---------- app/
                  |------ routes.py
                  |------ models.py
                  |------ __init__.py
                  |------ forms.py
                  |------ templates/
                              |-------- home.html
                              |-------- base.html
                  |------ static/
                            |-------css/
                                     |------- styles.css
                            |-------js/
                                     |------- app.js
```

All your configurations go to the `config.py` file.

You register your installed packages like flask, SQLAlchemy in `__init__.py`

Installed packages are written to `requirements.txt` file.

In your case, you need to install `flask`:

```py
(venv)$ pip3 install flask
```

Update your `requirements.txt` file:

```py
(venv)$ pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

Initialize your flask app in `_init_.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

import routes, models
```

All your routes will be in `routes.py`:

```py
from app import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

The logic to update your database will be in your routes.